How to take AWS Batch Job ID from Step Function?
I am setting up a pipeline where I take celery message from SQS, decode it and run AWS Step Function. Inside Step Function I am submitting AWS Batch Job that runs my python script.
The issue I am facing is that I want to update in my DRF API endpoint job_id field when the job is submitted so BEFORE docker container is started. However I am not sure how to take AWS Batch Job ID from Step Function before Running state in AWS Batch Job.
The only solution I see is to submit AWS Batch Job directly in my lambda function without starting Step Function but I do not want to do it this way because I have other pipelines running in Step Function so I want to keep consistency. That's why I am asking you for help. Maybe someone had similar case and is willing to help.
Below is my AWS Lambda and AWS Step Function definition.
lambda_function.py:
def start_step_function(step_function_input):
    state_machine_arn = os.environ['STEP_FUNCTION_ARN_MYAPP']

    response = client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn=state_machine_arn,
        input=json.dumps(step_function_input)
    )

    return response
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        for record in event['Records']:
            # Step 1: Decode the body
            body_json = decode_body(record['body'])
            
            # Step 2: Extract parameters
            step_function_input = extract_parameters(body_json)

            logger.info(f"Step Function input: {step_function_input}")
            
            # Step 3: Start the Step Function execution
            start_step_function(step_function_input)

        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Step Function executed successfully!')
        }
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing record: {e}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(f'Error processing record: {str(e)}')
        }

step function definition:
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "submit_my_job",
  "States": {
    "submit_my_job": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "my_job",
        "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:eu-west-1:380921374981:job-queue/my_job-worker-queue",
        "Parameters": {
          "TASK_ID.$": "$.task_id",
          "SPIDER_ID.$": "$.spider_id"
        },
        "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:eu-west-1:380921374981:job-definition/my_job"
      },
      "Next": "Success",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 5400,
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.TaskFailed"
          ],
          "Next": "Fail"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    },
    "Fail": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 5400
}

I've tried to add Step 4 in my lambda to see what can I take at this stage but I can only refer to step function ARN.
...
# Step 3: Start the Step Function execution
response = start_step_function(step_function_input)

# Extract jobID from the response (assuming it's in the response ARN)
job_id = response['executionArn'].split(':')[-1] # it is step function ID, not Batch job :(
task_id = step_function_input['task_id']

# Step 4: Update the task with the new job_id
update_task_in_my_api(task_id, {"job_id": job_id}, reason="Step Function execution completed")
completed")

Ideally I want to somehow take jobID from Step Function output, it looks like this when it is in Running state:

  "JobArn": "arn:aws:batch:eu-west-1:380921374981:job/53425042-22b2-4cad-a6a1-a7d881001702",
  "JobId": "53425042-22b2-4cad-a6a1-a7d881001702",
  "JobName": "my_job",
  "SdkHttpMetadata": {
    "AllHttpHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": [
        "X-amzn-errortype,X-amzn-requestid,X-amzn-errormessage,X-amzn-trace-id,X-amz-apigw-id,date"
      ],
      "x-amz-apigw-id": [
        "YesN4HTFDoEEXSw="
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Connection": [
        "keep-alive"
      ],
      "x-amzn-RequestId": [
        "91eab790-5e04-45bf-a94c-fa4891cda6d5"
      ],
      "Content-Length": [
        "169"
      ],
      "Date": [
        "Tue, 28 May 2024 11:32:15 GMT"
      ],
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
        "Root=1-6655c0bd-520650647e897a7fa51a62b7"
      ],
      "Content-Type": [
        "application/json"
      ]
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-amzn-errortype,X-amzn-requestid,X-amzn-errormessage,X-amzn-trace-id,X-amz-apigw-id,date",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "169",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Date": "Tue, 28 May 2024 11:32:15 GMT",
      "x-amz-apigw-id": "YesN4HTFDoEEXSw=",
      "x-amzn-RequestId": "91eab790-5e04-45bf-a94c-fa4891cda6d5",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6655c0bd-520650647e897a7fa51a62b7"
    },
    "HttpStatusCode": 200
  },
  "SdkResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "91eab790-5e04-45bf-a94c-fa4891cda6d5"
  }
}

My question is how can I take jobID and update my APIendpoint before my AWS Batch Job is started?

I don't 100% understand your need here, but may be because I'm not as familiar with AWS Batch and something that's happening internally. But the statement you made "how can I take jobID and update my API endpoint before my AWS Batch Job is started" seems to conflict with the design of the SubmitJob API Action for Batch (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html). The unique job is generated as a response to the API Call, but it seems you are looking to take some action before Batch begins running the job. Is that correct?

indeed, I want to submit my AWS Batch Job and get jobID from it, then send it to my API endpoint and update job_id field in my database

I think the best you can do is to use the "Request/Response" integration pattern when submitting your job from Step Functions rather than the "Run a Job (.sync)" pattern. The latter will have Step Functions monitor your batch job until completion and then continue the workflow. The former will continue the workflow immediately. You could then store the job id in your DB with a subsequent task. And if you wanted to have your workflow wait for completion, you'd need to implement a polling-loop against the DescribeJobs API Action.

However, if having this information in your database is necessary for the jobs to run properly, that will introduce a race condition (if the jobs themselves start before the workflow stores the data in your DB). So I think you might be asking for some sort of lifecycle hook in Batch or the ability to pass job context to the tasks. I don't know Batch well enough to give advice on what's possible there.
